# ASICs versus GPUs in Ethereum mining?

Tags: mining, gpu, asics, asic-resistant, progpow

Is there any way to assess the number of blocks being mined in Ethereum by ASICs versus the number of blocks being mined by GPUs percentage-wise?

Karim Helmy designed away to estimate the type of ASIC rig being used to mine Bitcoin based on analysis of the nonce. Is there something similar in the Ethereum network?

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum is ASIC-resistant which means its mining algorithm was designed in a way that using an ASIC would not be beneficial enough. Therefore, at least in theory, there shouldn't be many Ethereum ASICs around.

Every now and then some company claims they have a new Ethereum ASIC but I have no idea how true those claims are. Here's some news: https://cointelegraph.com/news/bitmains-antminer-e3-will-allegedly-stop-ethereum-mining-in-1-month-report (no big change in Ethereum mining has been detected so far)